# Why do wildcard import statements use classpath jar class instead of jdk classes?

Tags: java, java-io

Originally I had a java.io.File class in a jar in the classpath, which didn't have a separatorChar property.  So I ran into a problem where the following code block runs:

```
import java.io.File;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("separatorChar= " + File.separatorChar); 
    } 
}
```

But I changed the import statement as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
```

and then I get an error basically stating that File.separatorChar cannot be found.

What I believe is happening is import java.io.* is using a class that's in a jar in the classpath, whereas import java.io.File is specifically using the File class that comes with Java.

The question here is why does import java.io.File work while java.io.* does not?

Comment: You must have another class called File in the current package.

Comment: @EJP, that appears to have been the problem.  There must be some minor difference in the way the JVM is searching for the class though, because using import java.io.File, the correct class is used whereas import java.io.*, a different class is used.

Comment: That is correct. Import java.io.* gives the compiler another place to find classes that aren't in the current package. Import java.io.File tells the compiler which File to use. Moral: don't reuse JDK class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EJP commented on the original question,

> That is correct. Import java.io.* gives the compiler another place to find classes that aren't in the current package. Import java.io.File tells the compiler which File to use. Moral: don't reuse JDK class names.

Answer (score 1):

In an empty Project, the code still compiles with `import java.io.*`, so it seems that another class is used. If you use Eclipse, you can check the tooltip of `File` to see which class it is.

Alternatively, you can use

```
System.out.println(File.class.toString())
```

which will print out the class at runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to see which class is used in a headless environment?

Comment: Sure there is: write to a file.

Comment: Thanks @felix-freiberger, this verified my assumption that another class must have been present.  I updated my question to be more specific and provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You must have messed something else up somewhere.

When I compile

```
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("separatorChar= " + File.separatorChar); 
    } 
}
```

I get

```
c:\files\j>javac HelloWorld.java

c:\files\j>java HelloWorld
separatorChar= \
```

Answer (score -1):

when you use java.io.*; all you see is file, so instead of File.seperatorChar the route to get to separatorChar is io.file.separaterChar.  It deals with where the starting point is. It's like a file system... if you're in /users/matt and you type in /documents/mytext.txt the full path is C:/users/matt/documents/mytext.txt  If i back out to the users file, then the same command (/documents/mytext.txt) will look for C:/users/documents/mytext.txt which doesn't exist.  Hope that helps.

Comment: `io.File.separatorChar` **will not work.** Answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't meant to be a full answer, but more an explanation of what was happening.  you can never go more then 1 level below where you are.

Comment: But it didn't convey that, and that isn't the answer even when conveyed. The issue is quite different. * opens another package scope to search: File +directs+ the compiler to a specific class in a specific package scope.